# Turn ON without a screen or delay after power ON

Tags: pi-3, pi-4, power

I have RaspberryPI 4 and a few 3 that are hooked up to TV.

If power goes out, I have to grab a ladder and turn ON TV first and then hook up raspberryPi for it to start booting.

Is there a way to turn ON raspberry on power back with TV OFF?

Or is there a way to make it boot later lets say 30 secons after i cycle power as raspberry and TV are from same outlet. Having time to turn on TV.

I know i could make a hardware solution but is there a setting i am missing.
I tried with google suggestion but can not get it to work.

Comment: My Pi all boot without a monitor. You really need to explain what you are doing. (Also unregistered users get less help.)

Comment: I’m voting to close because this question is incoherent.

Comment: "*If power goes out, I have to grab a ladder and turn ON TV first and then hook up raspberryPi for it to start booting.*" This sentence in particular is confusing. How does a loss of power disconnect the RPi from its power supply? As soon as the power returns, the RPi will boot. It doesn't care whether there's a TV attached or turned on at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You can ssh into the Pi (over wireless if needed) and reboot the Pi as needed.

The following command will reboot the Pi.

`sudo reboot`

Answer (score 0):

You can delay the boot process by adding this line to the /boot/config.txt file (/boot/firmware/config.txt in Ubuntu):

```
boot_delay=20
```

This will delay the boot for 20 seconds (of course you can set different values).